# Prompting user for integer and adding to array in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

For my x86 Assembly Language class we were given an assignment wherein we needed to take in 12 integers and store them in an array called `Autumn`, and then display them. My question is why with this code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
Prompt1  BYTE "Please input a value:", 0
Autumn   WORD 12 DUP(?) 

.code
main PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET Autumn
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF Autumn
    call PromptForIntegers

    mov edi, OFFSET Autumn
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF Autumn

L2:
    mov eax, [edi]
    add edi, TYPE Autumn
    call WriteInt               ;Displays value in EAX
    call Crlf                   ;Moves to next output line
    loop L2

exit
main ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
PromptForIntegers PROC USES ecx edx esi
;
; Prompts the user for an arbitrary number of integers 
; and inserts the integers into an array.
; Receives: ESI points to the array, ECX = array size
; Returns:  nothing
;-----------------------------------------------------

    mov edx,OFFSET prompt1  

L1: call    WriteString     ; display string
    call    ReadInt         ; read integer into EAX
    call    Crlf            ; go to next output line
    mov [esi],eax           ; store in array
    add esi,TYPE SWORD      ; next integer
    loop    L1

    ret
PromptForIntegers ENDP
END main
```

When I input the integers 1 - 12 into the array. It prints out:

```
+131073
+196610
+262147
+327684
+393221
+458758
+524295
+589832
+655369
+720906
+786443
+12
```

The only correct output is the `+12`. The rest should be the numbers 1-11.

EDIT: Got it working for positive numbers by changing `mov eax, [edi]` to `mov ax, [edi]` in `L2`

Comment: `Autumn   WORD 12 DUP(?) ` seems wrong since you seem to be moving 32 bit data to it (ie. `mov [esi],eax`). Maybe you meant `Autumn  DWORD 12 DUP(?) `  ? Also think you need to change `add esi,TYPE SWORD` to `add esi,TYPE Autumn`

Comment: A bulk of you code is in the include file, but for purposes of your initial question, the comment hints `ECX = array size`. The `ecx` register is your loop counter. The value in `ecx` will be decremented by `1` each iteration until it is `0`. You need to set this value before you begin the loop. Also, if there is anything within the loop that can clobber the value of `ecx` you need to save the loop count by storing it, or pushing it onto the stack, do the computations, then pop it back of the stack before you reach `loop    L1` (push at start of loop, pop right before end)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Kip's Irvine32 library preserves all the registers except for return values for functions that actually return something (most often in _eax_). The  OP's code is okay in that regard. I think _ecx_ is properly defined with `mov ecx, LENGTHOF Autumn` which is the number of elements in the _Autumn_ array.

Comment: See, I learned something. I had no idea what was being the `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc`. Glad to know it is solid.